# Conflicting meta posts concerning game recommendations

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I'm a little bit confused by the close vote reason "Questions about Game Recommendations are off topic".

This meta post says they are On Topic. It has a score of +20:

- [Should we allow game recommendations? (Answer - YES, but...read on!)](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/298/6692)

This meta post says they are Off Topic. It's the one that is referenced in the Close Vote Reason, so I assume it reflects the current policy. It has a measly score of +6:

- [Help transform recommendations questions, desirable?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/970/6692)

Can we clean up meta so that the older, far more popular posts don't cast a shadow on the current policy? This could easily be done by editing the older post, or by deleting it entirely (except I'm sure that someone will attach a misplaced historical significance to it). If they are *on* topic, then can we clean up our close vote reasons?

Comment: Note that we also have http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/656/should-we-ban-game-recommendation-questions-done asked by the same person as the first question you linked, two years later. We also have http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/663/game-recommendation-questions-are-banned from the same person.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Wow, I don't think I titled this right. Where on earth did "questions about merchandise" come from? Sorry if that was confusing.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't confused. I was just pointing out that questions after the first one you linked to very clearly show that recommendation questions are off topic.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Ok, that's good (because I voted to close one today). I don't really care, but I think it would be cleaner to bury the old one.

Comment: The second question I linked is tagged [meta-tag:faq], and is therefore official. The site FAQ is also official. A random 4 year old question that nobody references is not official.

Comment: @murgatoid99 There are two parts to this question: 1) What is the current policy? and 2) Should we take action to make the current policy clearer? I understand that #1 is a duplicate, but #2 has not been brought up or addressed before.

Comment: The policy is very clear. The FAQ says game recommendation questions are not allowed. The answer linked to by the FAQ says that they are not allowed. The only relevant question in the [meta-tag:faq] tag says that they are not allowed. The fact that a 4-year-old discussion question expresses the opposite opinion does not invalidate that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17580/discussion-between-rainbolt-and-murgatroid99).

Answer (score 3):

Close [*Should we allow game recommendations [...]*](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/298/6692) as a duplicate of [*Game Recommendation questions are banned*](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/663/6692).

Anyone reading the first post could potentially be misled into believing that Game Recommendations are on topic. Closing it as a duplicate preserves its content while also directing users to the newer, updated policy. Everyone wins.

My vote has been cast (and has since expired).